# React Router Match Miss

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What is the advantage of using `Match` and `Miss` components from `react-router` over `Router` component? I cannot seem find any documentation about this in [react-router docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/docs).

My question spawns from looking at [react-universally](https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-universally) boilerplate, more exactly, by looking here: https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-universally

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`<Match>` and `<Miss>` were components in the alpha release of React Router v4.

In the beta, `<Match>` has been renamed `<Route>` (and its props have changed so that  `pattern` is now `path` and `exactly` is `exact`). The `<Miss>` component was removed entirely. Instead you should use a `<Switch>` statement, which will only render the first `<Route>` (or `<Redirect>`) that is matched. You can add a pathless component as the last child of the `<Switch>`'s routes and it will render when none of the preceding `<Route>`s match.

You can check out the [API documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/api) for more details.

```js
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
  <Route path='/about' component={About} />
  // The following <Route> has no path, so it will always
  // match. This means that <NoMatch> will render when none
  // of the other <Route>s match the current location.
  <Route component={NoMatch} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I've looked the docs and couldn't find anything hence my question. Thanks a lot! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks just ran into this problem as well, watch a tutorial video.

Answer (score 1):

And to add to the last post, you'll find this in `react-router-dom`. It's no longer in the react-router core library.

Here's a pattern I have found works for react routing. Same as previous posters, basically. You'll need to build the additional components included.

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
```

{/* Import your components here */}

```
class Root extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
             <Router>
                     <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={App} /> )} />
                        <Route path="/some-component"  component={SomeComponent} /> 
                        <Route component={NotFound}/>
                    </Switch>
             </Router>
        );
    }
 } 
        
render(<Root/>, document.querySelector('#main'));
```