# 'react-router' does not contain an export named 'BrowserRouter'

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router version 5.5.1 and am trying to use it in my `index.js` file:

```
./src/index.js
14:8-21 'react-router' does not contain an export named 'BrowserRouter'
```

The import statement within my `index.js`:

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Match, Miss } from 'react-router';
```

Comment: Use 3.x version LOL

Comment: @asiniy i'm a beginner so I'm not sure why I'd have to go back to an older version. I've tried to update my react-router & react using `npm update -g react react-router` but the error wasn't resolved.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you need to import `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom`

`import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'`

more info about [BrowserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter)

Comment: I did that but then I got the same error for `Match`.

Comment: Match was renamed to Route, check more in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362457/react-router-match-miss

Answer (score 8):

BrowserRouter is a part of `react-router-dom` so you've to import it from `react-router-dom`.

`import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'`

`Match` and `Miss` were components in alpha release of `react-router`. `Match` has been changed to `Route` and `Miss` has been removed. You can use `Switch` instead of `Miss`

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362457/react-router-match-miss) about `Match` and `Miss`

Answer (score 1):

There was an error in your import. `BrowserRouter` is a part of `react-router-dom`. so you've to import it from `react-router-dom`.

`import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'`

Answer (score 0):

BrowserRouter is in react-router-dom as others have stated. V4 is very different from v3. I recommend looking at their guide to see how to use it. And any examples you look for should be for version 4.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web

Answer (score 0):

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
```

**Issue:**

'Route' is not exported from 'react-router-dom' (imported as 'Router').

**Solution:**

Just close the localhost and Re-run the npm start, its works fine

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for your contribution. To maximize the chances of helping others, please consider adding a little more exposition to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I had same issue with Link from react-router-dom. I resolved it by installing same version of react-route and react-router-dom. Looks like react-router-dom doesn't have Link in it.

```
yarn add react-router react-router-dom
```